# how to assign month days value to div in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables

I have been trying to learn and do some practice on my own by creating a calendar using javascript, HTML, and CSS. However, I have created some magic successfully like to get current month and year and previous month and year by clicking a button in HTML, but I m stuck to an extend where I m not able to get the days in proper format, I tried to use some learning resources from w3schools and google but seems like I'm still lacking my knowledge.

Please see that I m trying to create days such that I can show them in div/grid which I have created in HTML and Grid using CSS.
I also do apologize if this sounds very easy and funny question as the other question shows things related to jquery and I m only looking for a Javascript solution to learn.

When I tried below code:
HTML :

```
<div id="caldays"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
  let days="";
    for (let i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
        days = days +  i;
        caldays.innerHTML = days;
        
    }
```

The result:
[image]

Other Javascript Code using div

```
 let days="";
    for (let i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
        days = days +  "<div> $[i] </div>";
        caldays.innerHTML = days;
        
    }
```

The result:

[image]

Could you please let me know what am I missing or doing wrong and how can this be corrected?

Thank you for your valuable help and guidance all experts in advance. Also please see that I have been trying to learn from this link https://medium.com/@nitinpatel_20236/challenge-of-building-a-calendar-with-pure-javascript-a86f1303267d but trying to use div and not table or rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use backticks (``) in template-literals at the pace of `"`double-quotes.
2. Use `{ }` curly braces at the place of `[ ]` square brackets.

```js
let days = "";
for (let i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
  days = days + `<div> ${i} </div>`;
  caldays.innerHTML = days;
}
```

```html
<div id="caldays"></div>
```

Also, you can directly assign `<div> ${i} </div>` to `innerHTML`. And when there is only one line of code inside a block you can omit the `{ }` curly braces. Like this:

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 31; i++) caldays.innerHTML += `<div> ${i} </div>`;
```

```html
<div id="caldays"></div>
```

---

**Some Useful resources:**

- [Template literals (Template strings) Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [Getting Literal With ES6 Template Strings](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings)

Comment: That's really great help from you sir and I really appreciate a quick response.  

Thank you so much. @ManasKhandelwal